# Suppressing unnecessary @throws annotations when new DateTime() should never throw when called without arguments?

Tags: php, date, datetime, exception, phpdoc

So, the question itself is pretty simple, but I want to discuss it and find out other people's opinion about it.

As far as I can understand, `DateTime` constructor throws when you pass invalid arguments and it fails to make something meaningful with them, but what about the case, when you don't pass anything and it uses it's default values? Seems like there will never be an error in that case.

```php
$date = new DateTime();
```

The problem is that PHPDocs adds unnecessary `@throws`, even if this will never `throw`. Would it be safe to create some kind of a helper-function to avoid unnecessary `@throws` in PHPDocs, that would just suppress this exception, which is never thrown anyway, and make code cleaner? Or is there another way to suppress this elegantly?

```php
/**
 * Suppresses exception on current DateTime
 * creation, which is anyway never thrown.
 *
 * @return DateTime
 */
function getCurrentDateTime(): DateTime
{
    try {
        return new DateTime();
    } catch (Exception $e) {}
}
```

So, what's your experience on this and do you have any similar function on your project?

P.S: I understand that there are a lot of frameworks and libraries like Carbon that allow you never face this kind of problems, but I'm still curious about finding a good way of handling them without any third party solutions :)

Comment: Does it make sense to write a function that wraps `new DateTime` in a `try`/`catch` when you know it will never throw an `Exception`? No. It doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: One should also note that even *if* the constructor throws an Exception for whatever reason you will never get back an object. So this is even more pointless by that measure.

Comment: @Sherif the point is to prevent IDE from adding `@throws` PHPDocs in places, where they are useless

Comment: Disable the inspection in your IDE, problem solved. PHP does not have checked exceptions.

Comment: There's some good reading here ~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586882/php-or-other-strategy-to-deal-with-exceptions-that-cannot-occur

Comment: @Phil complete disabling is not something i look for, because most of the times these inspections do help